# Can't create new Drill storage plugin for s3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-drill

I'm having trouble creating a new Drill Storage Plugin for AWS S3.  I'm following [these instructions](http://drill.apache.org/blog/2014/12/09/running-sql-queries-on-amazon-s3/):

> 1. Point your browser to http://:8047
> 2. Select the 'Storage' tab.
> 3. A good starting configuration for S3 can be entirely the same as the dfs  plugin, except the connection parameter is changed to s3://bucket. So first select the Update button for dfs, then select the text area and copy it into the clipboard (on Windows, ctrl-A, ctrl-C works).
> 4. Press Back, then create a new plugin by typing the name into the New Storage Plugin, then press Create. You can choose any name, but a good convention is to use s3- so you can easily identify it later.
> 5. In the configuration area, paste the configuration you just grabbed from 'dfs'. Change the line connection: "file:///" to connection: "s3://".
> 6. Click Update. You should see a message that indicates success.

I completed the steps before this section (ie. modifying `hadoop_excludes.txt` and making a `core-site.xml`). In the steps posted above, I made it to step 5, but for step 6, my screen shows no "Update" button, only "Create" and "Back". ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmS12.jpg) here, as I can't post images.)

If I click Create, nothing happens.  If I click Back, I'm taken back to the main Storage Plugin page, and my entry isn't there.  (If I click Create and then Back, it doesn't save, either.)

Here's the configuration text I'm using (copied from dfs plugin):

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "s3:///",
  "workspaces": {
    "root": {
      "location": "/",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    },
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "psv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tbl"
      ],
      "delimiter": "|"
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "delimiter": ","
    },
    "tsv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tsv"
      ],
      "delimiter": "\t"
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    },
    "json": {
      "type": "json"
    },
    "avro": {
      "type": "avro"
    }
  }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Any advice is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Problem solved - I was running the Drill Web UI in Chrome, which doesn't have Java support.  When I ran in Firefox I was able to make this new Storage Plugin successfully.